How to propertly define what this references to in JSDOC?
I come this time with a very simple question. Is there a way, on JSDOC, to describe what this represents in a class?


/**
 * This is a very simplified version of what is going on
 *
 * I want to add something here to indicate that, inside this function, `this` === CalledClass, 
 * so autocomplete for parameters/etc work
 */
const unboundedFunction = function () { 
    console.log(this);
    this.parameter = 50;
}

class CalledClass {
  parameter = 'test';

  callOutsideFunction() {
    unboundedFunction.bind(this)();
  }

}

const obj = new CalledClass();
obj.callOutsideFunction();




Why don't you make it a method in the class? Then this is automatically an instance of that class.

Another option is to use let self = this; and then use JSDOC to declare the type of self.

Because I have a set of functions on our module that have a n-1 relationship with CalledClass. When initializing the class you pass which callback to use, and bind the current object to it

Still not sure why they can't be methods. Pass this.functionName.bind(this)

https://jsdoc.app/tags-this
/** @this CalledClass  */
const unboundedFunction = function () { 
    console.log(this);
    this.parameter = 50;
}

class CalledClass {
  parameter = 'test';

  callOutsideFunction() {
    unboundedFunction.bind(this)();
  }

}

const obj = new CalledClass();
obj.callOutsideFunction();

